# How to use Zest from Eclipse Marketplace?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace, zest

On the Eclipse Marketplace, I installed Zest. Now I am wondering, how I can use it?

Where are the library files (jars)? And how to add them?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get started is by creating a plug-in project with a dependency on the Zest bundles.

Check out the [tutorial by Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseZest/article.html) for a nice step-by-step intro. There is also documentation available from within Eclipse (Help -> Help Contents) and [on the wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest/DOT).

Note that the Marketplace version now provides the latest version of Zest which is part of GEF4 and has a new namespace `org.eclipse.gef4.zest.*` instead of `org.eclipse.zest.*`.